# Email uniqueness check in azure

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

There is email claim in Azure, so if I use username as local account login, is it possible somehow to prevent users to signup with same email, even if they use different usernames?

Comment: Are you using Azure AD B2C? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Yes, B2C. And I think it is impossible to do. So there is email field in user details (not username field). So now I can register multiple users by using same email but different usernames event if it verify that email. I want that same email can be used only once.